# com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory ClassNotFoundException

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, activejdbc, activeweb

Hi I am new to web development and am trying to get activejdbc to connect to a cloud sql instance... I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.javalite:db-migrator-maven-plugin:1.4.11:migrate (dev_migrations) on project activeweb-simple: Execution dev_migrations of go
al org.javalite:db-migrator-maven-plugin:1.4.11:migrate failed: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket fa
ctory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception:  -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.javalite:db-migrator-maven-plugin:1.4.11:migrate (dev_migrations) on project
activeweb-simple: Execution dev_migrations of goal org.javalite:db-migrator-maven-plugin:1.4.11:migrate failed: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransien
tConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception:
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution dev_migrations of goal org.javalite:db-migrator-maven-plugin:1.4.11:migrate failed: com.m
ysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying ex
ception:
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.javalite.db_migrator.MigrationException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'c
om.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception:
        at org.javalite.db_migrator.DbUtils.openConnection(DbUtils.java:183)
        at org.javalite.db_migrator.maven.AbstractDbMigrationMojo.openConnection(AbstractDbMigrationMojo.java:178)
        at org.javalite.db_migrator.maven.AbstractDbMigrationMojo.openConnection(AbstractDbMigrationMojo.java:170)
        at org.javalite.db_migrator.maven.MigrateMojo.executeMojo(MigrateMojo.java:21)
        at org.javalite.db_migrator.maven.AbstractDbMigrationMojo.executeCurrentConfiguration(AbstractDbMigrationMojo.java:96)
        at org.javalite.db_migrator.maven.AbstractDbMigrationMojo.execute(AbstractDbMigrationMojo.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due
to underlying exception:
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3194)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:293)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2232)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.javalite.db_migrator.DbUtils.openConnection(DbUtils.java:181)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3192)
    ... 43 more
```

My connection string in database.properties looks like this:

```
development.url=jdbc:mysql://google/database?cloudSqlInstance=project:location:instance&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=dbuser&password=dbuserpassword&useSSL=false
```

I have used the same connection string with spring-hibernate configuration with out a problem, but would like to try activeweb-activejdbc.  Why the compiler cannot find the class?  I have included google cloud sql dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to include a fill stack trace. Second, if you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, this means you do not have that class on the classpath. You need to know for a fact that the class is there. Use Maven dependency plugin, or expand all your dependent jar files and ensure you have the class. No magic here:)

UPDATE: 
Now that you provided the stack trace, I see that the exception happens when you run the migrator. If you look at the migrator configuration, you will see that it requires its own class path. For instance, the example here: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-simple/blob/master/pom.xml#L39 lists the MySQL JDBC driver especially for the migrator, even if you have it configured already for the project runtime. Just copy the config, and replace the MySQL driver with your driver.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I checked that the class is there in: ".m2\repository\com\google\cloud\sql\mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6\1.0.2\mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6-1.0.2.jar\com\google\cloud\sql\mysql\" and I am using the maven dependency as posted originally in the question, so I dont understand why the compiler is not finding th class...

Comment: Thanks, had not noticed the dependencies on db-migrator, changed that and it connected successfully.

Comment: great, happy to help!